# Issue with the for loop not working correctly

Tags: bash, shell

I have multiple jobs which runs based on file indicators.
I am looking to build a unix script to flag the job based on if the file is present for the current day of previous day.
I am maintaining a csv file with the below records in it and a Interval column ( which is in hours).
If the difference of the current time and the modification time of the file ( in hours) is more than what is there in the csv file then it will be flagged as old day file.

```
-sh-4.2$ cat scorecard_file_details.csv
Scorecard_Name,Path,FileName,Time_Interval_HRS
Scorecard_LDO_ABC_BTS,/NAS/IDQ/Bank_SEN,ABC.EXT,12
Scorecard_LDO_PQR_BTS,/NAS/IDQ/Bank_Prof,PQR.EXT,6
```

The files come at different path which is path in the above csv file.
Now, I want to  match the file name for the csv with the filename at it's corresponding path and get the data may be in another file ( filename, path, flag).

I have come up with the below script but it is currently not returning anything at the highlighted (Bold) step ( it's incomplete as of now).

can anyone please help why the below for is not returning anything although the cat is working fine?
Also, any help with the logic is appreciated.

```
set -x
CSV_File_Path=/NAS/Target/DQ
**for FileName in $(cat scorecard_file_details.csv | awk -F "," '{ print $3 }'); do
echo $Filename**
CURTIME=$(date +%s)
File_Path=`awk '{ print $2 }'` $FileName
cd $File_Path
Files_in_Path=`ls -ltr | awk '{ print $9 }'`

for files in $Files_in_Path ; do

if [[ "$Files_in_Path" = $FileName ]]; then
TIMEDIFF=echo $(( ($(date +%s) - $(stat $files  -c %Y)) / 3600 ))
echo $files","$TIMEDIFF >> /NAS/Target/DQ/file_with_difference.txt
 else
echo "File is not present"
fi
done
<<Logic to flag based on time difference and interval>>
done
set +x
```

Comment: I wouldn't parse the output of ls in Files_in_Path=`ls -ltr | awk '{ print $9 }'` Instead use find with printf %Ts This way you don't need to use stat further along.either

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest you redesign your script to use `find` command with `-printf` format option and combination of `-mtime | -ctime | -mmin | -cmin` filters.

Using `find` command you can filter a combination of time differences, type, name, path and more. Also assign actions on found files.

Please read intro tutorial [here](https://shapeshed.com/unix-find/). And detailed manpage [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html).

In short you can push the time difference calculation into the `find` command, and than operate on the found files.

For example:

```
$ find /tmp -mmin +60 -and -mmin -150   -printf "%p %AF %AT \n"
```

Find files in `/tmp` folder.

That `-mmin +60 -and -mmin -150` modified more than 60 min ago and modified less than 150 min ago.

Print the found files as `file path`=`%p` `file create date`=`%AF` `file create time`=`%AT`

Output:

```
/tmp/Low 2020-11-12 20:16:45.1960274000
/tmp/StructuredQuery.log 2020-11-12 20:55:00.3057165000
/tmp/~DF3465C10364E2CAFE.TMP 2020-11-12 20:16:45.7578495000
/tmp/~DFAC3AC652357DBBED.TMP 2020-11-12 20:16:46.1726618000
/tmp/~DFC2B1A30DCA4CA52A.TMP 2020-11-12 20:16:46.3941610000
```

Comment: Thanks @Dudi Boy-- but my requirement here is slightly different . Each of the file has different time interval on the basis of which I have to identify if it's old or new